# Kibana: Displaying filters next to log messages in the dashboard

Tags: kibana

I am able to show the log messages on the dashboard using Data Table visualization. However I also want to show the filters next to the messages like shown in the attached image (bottom left).
I know I can apply the same filters by expanding the message but this way looks more convenient.
Can I still do it on Kibana 5.5 or was this present only in older version?[image: Example Kibana Dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

With Kibana Version 5.5.0 you can do that while creating a Data Table Visualization.

You can follow the following steps to achieve it:-

1. Click on Visualize Tab and click on (+ symbol) to create a new Visualization.
2. Select Data Table as Visualization Type.
3. Select an index or saved search.
4. Now when you are taken to the Visualization Editor Page, there on the top bar just below the search bar, you can see an option of **Add a Filter.**
5. Upon clicking the above option, you will be shown the list of fields which you can filter.

Attaching the screenshot for the same.

[image: Add a Filter Option in Data Table Visualization]

Comment: Thanks for your response Yuvraj. However I don't want to add filters while creating a visualization. I want to do the filtering directly from the dashboard. For e.g. if i want to view messages of specific log level, then I should be able to specify it from the dashboard directly. Hope you got what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: The dashboard pane also has the same option of Adding a Filter which is present in same location as in Visualization Page. You can use the filters in dashboard in this way. I can edit my above answer if it suffices your condition.

Comment: But that will apply for all visualizations, right? What if I want to do this only for the log messages. My idea is that I show all the logs messages in this pane and then users can filter further based on need without disturbing rest of the visualizations

Answer (score 0):

(don't have the required reputation to add a comment yet, so I have to post a full answer)

Following up on your conversation with Yuvraj Gupta, as far as I know, when you apply a filter, it gets applied to the entire dashboard.

You can always create a different dashboard containing just the logs so any filters applied will not disturb anything else. Then you can have the dashboards automatically rotate so you can see both.